# Command causes error in SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

Why do I receive an error message for this?

```
<?php
$output ="";
$query = "HELP;";
$output = mysql_query($query, $emailTrackerConnection) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

The output I receive:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @JW. It does have the HELP command http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/help.html

Comment: According to TFM you need a search string http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/help.html

Comment: help alone is not a query

Answer (score 3):

`HELP;` (without parameters) is an internal command of the MySQL command line tool rather than a SQL command:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1862
Server version: 5.1.39-community MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

However, if you add a search string you do get a [SQL command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/help.html):

> HELP 'search_string'

Answer (score 1):

you show specify a keyword when using `HELP`, eg.

```
HELP 'contents'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/5444)
- [HELP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/help.html)

Answer (score 1):

`HELP ;` will return this error. Try using `HELP 'statement or keyword or operator' ;` to get help on a specific keyword.

If you want to find what keywords/operators/statements are available for use with `HELP`, use this:

```
HELP '%' ;
```